# Using DynamoDBEnhancedAsyncClient to scan and fetch futureObject

Tags: spring-boot, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

I am trying to use v2 library to persist & retrieve data in non-blocking manner.
Put method of **DynamoDBEnhancedAsyncClient** returns CompletableFuture object but scan and query methods return PagePublisher object - that tends to tell me that this is a blocking call. Can someone please help me understand/fix this. I want to implement end-to-end non-blocking calls. I tried with **DynamoAsyncClient** and that works perfect but I want to get rid of manually mapping of objects using *DynamoDBEnhancedAsyncClient**, but I see no method that returns CompletableFutures.

Here is my code block

```
DynamoDbAsyncTable<User> asyncTable = dynamoDBEnhancedAsyncClient.table("userTable", TableSchema.fromBeab(User.class));
Map<String, AttribiuteValue> expVal = new HashMap();
expVal.put(":val", AttributeValue.builder().n(String.valueOf(userId)).build());
Expression exp = Expression.builder().expression("userId = :val").expressionValues(expVal).build();
ScanEnhancedRequest req  = ScanEnhancedRequest.builder().filterExpression(exp).build();
PagePublisher<User> pagePublisher = asyncTable.scan(req);
```

Dependencies I used

```
<dependency>
<groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
<artifactId>dynamodb</artifactid>
<version>2.10.76</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
<artifactId>dynamodb-enhanced</artifactid>
<version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS SDK v2 leverages [reactive streams](https://www.reactive-streams.org/) to build its asynchronous functions.

`PagePublisher<T>` won't make your call blocking, this class implements the `Publisher`([doc](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.3-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Publisher.html)) interface which allows you to subscribe on it.

### Option1

According to your question which you would like to transfer `Publisher` to `CompletableFuture`, here is a rough example of how to do it:

```
var publisher = asyncTable.scan(req);
var future = new CompletableFuture<Page<User>>();
publisher.subscribe(
    new Subscriber<>() {
      @Override
      public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        s.request(1);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(Page<User> userPage) {
        future.complete(userPage);
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable t) {
        future.completeExceptionally(t);
      }

      @Override
      public void onComplete() {
        future.complete(null);
      }
    });
var result = future.join();
```

### Option2 (Recommended)

However, I saw you tagged this question with `spring-boot` and you mention that you want to implement nonblocking end to end calls.

I **highly recommend** you to integrate [Spring Webflux](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/) with AWS SDK v2, which makes you to create a nonblocking/reactive web service easier.

By adopting Spring Webflux, you can integrate your code like:

```
Mono.from(asyncTable.scan(req))
```

which makes the code cleaner and simpler.